# Handle popup login box in Selenium

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver

How to handle popup login box in Java and Selenium? I used http://espn.go.com "sign in a popup box" but all the time I get

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='login-title']"}
```

Here is my test code

```
@Test
    public void testLogin(){    
        espn().navigation().signInBtn();
        espn().login().verifyLoginPage(" Log In");
        espn().login().enterUserName("test");
        espn().login().enterPassword("test");
        espn().login().clickLogInBtn();
        espn().login().verifyLoginError("Email Address and password were not found. Please try again.");
    }
```

Comment: use `driver.getWindowHandles()` and switch to current window and proceed with ur execution. Once done switch back to default content

Comment: still getting same thing

Comment: Your xpath seems to be wrong...its `.//*[@id='submitBtn']` if I am seeing the right log in button and its under an iframe, switch to the iframe..

Comment: there is nothing wrong with locator its just not getting the page element

Comment: can u please provide the screenshot or html of the page?

Comment: can you go  http://espn.go.com and click on Sign in button and see your own

Comment: as i said earlier you need to switch to the iframe first...

Answer (score 0):

**Username and password fields are present in 'iframe'.** 
Selenium not able to find the elements present in frames. So we need to switch the driver to frame and identify the elements present in that frame.
First switch driver to frame using **driver.switchTo().frame(By.name(""));**

Now try to identify the username and password. Once password and username enterd, click 'Login'.

Now again switch the driver to default content using "**driver.switchTo().defaultContent()**" which will make Selenium to interact with elements outside the frame.